# Import in JS in a specific way

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TS, I have **Class1** from *class.ts*, some functions from *helper.ts*, some variables from *variables.ts*:

For example, *variables.ts* looks like that:

```
export const test1 = 'test1';
export const test2 = 0;
export const test3 = 'test3';
export const test4 = 'test4';
```

Then with Webpack, I give the api.ts like the entry to build a module.

*api.ts*

```
export { Class1 } from './class1';
export { helper1, helper2 } from './helper';
import * as variables from './utils/common-variables';
export { variables };
```

Everything is fine when I need all the variables of the *variables.ts*.
I can do this in my file.js:

```
import { variables } from 'api';
```

However, sometimes, I only need one variable. So, I would like to know if it was possible to import something like this:

```
import { variables.test1 as test } from 'api';
```

Comment: you can also re-export every single variables from `api.ts`, as in `export * from './utils/common-variables';`. Then you can import single variables directly from `api` as in `import { test1 } from 'api'`

Comment: You mean to export two times `'./utils/common-variables';` ? Once to get everything in one variable and the other time every single variable ? @GiovanniGonzaga

Comment: Yes, not necessarily suggesting it, just saying it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that particular syntax is [not possible – an `ImportSpecifier` can only really be a name](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#prod-ImportSpecifier), not an attribute access expression like you have.

You can just import them directly from `api/utils/common-variables` instead, though, and get rid of the re-export.

Comment: So sad ... :'-(

Comment: However, I can not import like this "api/utils/common-variables" because it's bundled and minified with webpack @AKX

Answer (score 0):

You can import a single module from an import and rename it as you want in typescript. It has been mentioned in the documentation, [read here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

sample:

```
import { ZipCodeValidator as ZCV } from "./ZipCodeValidator";
let myValidator = new ZCV();`
```

I hope this helps.